# Change jQuery click event (this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont know a lot about js and jQuery.

I bought a WP theme and I want to do a few changes on it.

In this page: https://websitesdevs.com/search-services/

You can see a div with a text saying "Apply Filters" and when you click on it, it opens a popup with all the filters. The thing is that I want a search box, and then a button to open this popup with the filters.. I've been trying it but I can't do it.. I would like to open that popup with any other CSS class. Do you know how can I do it?

I think that the popup opens with this JS & jQuery script

```
    //filter dropdown
jQuery('.mmobile-floating-apply,.wt-mobile-close').on('click', function() {
    var _this = jQuery(this);
    _this.parents('aside.wt-sidebar').toggleClass('show-mobile-filter');
});
```

This code is located at workreap_callbacks.js

Thanks for your time, I really need this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you can run this:

```
$('.mmobile-floating-apply,.wt-mobile-close')
  .parents('aside.wt-sidebar')
  .toggleClass('show-mobile-filter');
```

from any place in your code.

Comment: Hi Maxim, thanks for your answer.. Where I'm supposed to put that code? I would like to do a button to open that popup and I was thinking about togle it with a css class, it's that possible?

Comment: You have to run this code as a callback to your button onclick event.
I don't think you can trigger this code by adding/removing class on some other element.